# how to convert NSArray into String swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have an array result

```
["https://woo.demoapp.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/sunglasses.jpg"]
```

i try to convert to string url in tableview and show image with SDWebImage

```
    let dic = productArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let image = dic.object(forKey: "images") as! NSArray
    let imageUrl = image.value(forKey: "src") as! NSArray as! [String]

    cell.pinImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "pin1"))
```

Comment: It's recommended in Swift 3 to avoid NSStuff, like NSDictionary, NSArray when there is the Swift Equivalent available. What the result you gave ?`imageUrl`? If that's the case `URL(string: imageUrl)` will clearly fail, because `imageUrl` is said to be `as! NSArray as! [String]`, not a String. `URL(string: imageUrl.first)`? But your parsing seems wrong (there isn't one, try to use custom class/struct). It should be corrected.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? You only told about your requirement not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have getting array then you used below code.

In Swift objectAtIndex: 0 looks like this:

```
let srcImage:NSDictionary = image[0] as! NSDictionary
let strImageUrl:NSString = srcImage.value(forKey: "src") as! NSString
```

### Updated:

```
let srcImage = image[0] as! [String: Any]
let strImageUrl = srcImage["src"] as! String
```

Comment: **Do not** use `NSDictionary` in Swift. **Do not** use `NSString` in Swift.  **Do not** annotate types the compiler can infer in Swift. **Do not** use `valueForKey` at all in this case.

Comment: @vadia in question used NSDictionary, NSString then i use it.

Comment: This is no reason to adopt bad habits. ;-)